# ImportXML function in Google Sheets to pull out data from first column

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to import data from the first column of [this web table](https://daso.archives.gov.ua/wp-content/earchives/storage/metrics/metrics.html), using Google Sheets ImportXML and ARRAYFORMULA functions

So I want to get a column with these numbers:

007679961
007679962
007679963
....
007829037

Table content is constantly being updated and number of rows keeps growing, rows are regularly being added to the end or inserted somewhere in the middle. The structure of the table is constant.

Could someone suggest a good formula for my case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Too big to use importhtml, so, try this simplified solution

```
=import1stColumn(A1)
```

with

```
function import1stColumn(url) {
  var source = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText().replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r|\t|  )/gm,"");
  var regex = /(<([^>]+)>)/ig;
  var data = [];
  var html = source.substring(source.indexOf('<TABLE'),source.indexOf('</TABLE'))
  var trs = html.split('<TR')
  for (var i=2;i<trs.length;i++){
    var tds = trs[i].split('<TD')
    data.push([('<TD'+tds[1]).replace(regex,"")])
  }
  return(data);
}
```

[image]

Comment: and how NOT to include columns header? Eg. not to have "1" in the first row.

Comment: ok, done, I have amended my answer